# Second "check all" functionality doesn't run

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've got a function that is supposed to check all the checkboxes if there are some that are not checked. If they are all checked it will then uncheck them all.

It works as expected until you click the `check all` link for the third time.

1. first click checks them all
2. second click unchecks them all
3. third click is supposed to check them all again, but doesn't

```
function CheckAll(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[[]/g, '\\[').replace(/]/g, '\\]');

    if ($('input[name=' + name + ']:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {
        $('input[name=' + name + ']:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('input[name=' + name + ']:checkbox:checked').attr('checked', false);
    }
}
```

Simple HTML

```
    <a href="#" onclick="CheckAll('users[]')">Check All</a><br/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]" checked="checked"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="users[]"/><br/>
```

[**jsFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/3U7bq/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()` if you are using jquery 1.6+

After that version, properties are handled different than attributes, and the checked is a property not an attribute.

What is happening, is .attr() only checks if the attribute exists, it doesn't care what the value is. So checked="false" will still return `true`, if you use .attr().

If you use .prop(), it will correctly return the property value, which in the example I've given, would be false.

Comment: You my friend, are a hero. A+

Answer (score 0):

You've already suggested to use `prop()`  instead of `.attr()`. And I think you can achieve your result using a less code:

```
function CheckAll(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[[]/g, '\\[').replace(/]/g, '\\]'),
    checkboxes = 'input[name=' + name + ']:checkbox';
    $(checkboxes).prop('checked', $(checkboxes + ':checked').length !== $(checkboxes).length);
}
```

Comment: This is also a nice solution.  Thanks for the tip :)